# Pickle не работает // Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, словарь, pickle

Почему

```
elif message.text.startswith("Если сообщение равно"):
        global keys
        global value
        global command
        keys= re.findall(r'равно (.*?) отправить',message.text)
        keys = ''.join(keys)
        value = re.findall(r'текст (.*?);',message.text)
        value = ''.join(value)
        command[keys] = value
        with open('data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(command, f)
        global command_new
        command_new = {}
        with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
            command_new = pickle.load(f)
        print(command_new)
        await message.answer("Комманда успешно создана: \nif message.text ==" + keys + ":\n    await message.answer(" + command[keys] + ")")
    elif message.text in command_new: 
        await message.answer(command_new[message.text])
```

В этом коде, во втором условии, **command_new** *не найден*?

Comment: Так у вас чтение `command_new` в другой ветке происходит. Как во вторую ветку попадут данные из первой ветки?

Comment: Мне надо сделать её глобальной?

Comment: Вам надо разобраться с логикой вашего кода, а не гадать. Когда куда попадает управление и что вы хотите вообще

Comment: как мне получить словарь из pickle файла и сохранить его в переменную?

Comment: Ну вы это же делаете, только в другой ветке кода. Но проверить в `elif` вы так не сможете, это надо где-то выше тогда читать из файла